# Lambda function in python for uploading multiple files to aws s3

Tags: python-2.7, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Greetings good people!

A newbie to aws lambda and a below average to python.

I'm struggling to find  a lambda function written in python to upload some application logs that are logrotated (bunch of .gz files)from multiple ec2 instances to a s3 bucket. I ran in to a few examples but very ashamed to say that I couldn't decipher the code all that well given my little or no experience.

-OS is centos6
-path: /app/logs/*.date.gz

Please can someone bring me up to speed on this? Please try to include comments appropriately  for clarity because I really want to learn.

Please help out gentleman.

Thanks so much

-bindo

Comment: How would the Lambda function be able to access the files inside the EC2 instances? This sounds like something I would use a cron job for, not Lambda.

Comment: @MarkB, Thanks so much. I thought that it was possible after seeing the post by Pol in "stackoverflow.com/questions/40187728/how-to-use-aws-lambda-to-backup-an-s3-object-to-a-bucket-on-another-account".

Comment: That post is talking about files in an S3 bucket, not on an EC2 server.

Comment: Thanks again Mark. I believe that the only way to achieve this is to run a script locally on either ec2 instances?